# index.do will download but will not open

Tags: website

I need to access a website that has changed its `index.html` to `index.do` for some reason. Now when I click it doesn't open, just tries to download. I use Ubuntu and Chromium daily but I've tried a selection of browsers and IE on Windows 7 (ugh), same result.

Interested to see whether anyone has the same problem and whether there's a simple solution. I seem to remember that with older browsers there was a setting to add non-standard extensions.

Comment: Issue could well be server side, not parsing the script but instead trying to get you to download and open it...  Could be that it is sending a PDF file or similar, but not sending a proper content type header and suggested filename. But if it is multiple OSes and multiple browsers it isn't on your end...

Answer (score 1):

It is almost certainly an issue with the web server. Typically, web servers are configured to map "handlers" to server-side file extensions, sometimes also folders or some other URL. It's then up to the server to load that handler and process the HTTP request sent from your browser. Browsers can't view everything they receive from a server, as in the case when you click a link to a zip file, exe, etc. If the server wants the file to be displayed as content (not a download) it must set the HTTP response headers to allow the browser to know how to handle it, usually by setting the content-type header to text/html, image/*, etc. If the server doesn't do this, the browser doesn't have a clue about the content, and WONT guess, it will just assume the content is a download. Report the issue to the webmaster for the problem site.